# How to replace brackets with parentheses but keep contents between them?

Tags: vim

I have the following string in vim:

```
if [ a == 100 ]
```

I want to change it to:

```
if (( a==100 ))
```

And I want to replace the bracket with parentheses and keep the content as they are,
I try:

```
:%s/if \[ .* \]/if (( .* ))/g
```

and I got:

```
if (( .* ))
```

How can I just get the original content?
Thank you guys in advance. :)

Comment: `sed 's/\[ a == 100 \]/test "$a" -eq 100/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
%s/if \[\(.*\)\]/if ((\1))/
```

This uses backreferences, i.e, capturing what's between the meta-parenthesis and projects the captured content using `\<number>` according to the capture order.

You don't really need the `g` flag since shell scripts unlikely have multiple `if`s on the same line.

Answer (score 6):

Not to refute Rafael's answer, but as another, perhaps more general solution to working with surrounding character pairs: this is what Tim Pope's wonderful [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin is for.

1. Place cursor on or inside square brackets
2. <kbd>cs])</kbd> **C**hange **s**urrounding square brackets (**]**) to parentheses (**)**)
3. <kbd>vi)</kbd> **V**isually select **i**nside parentheses (**)**)
4. <kbd>S)</kbd> **S**urround visual selection with parentheses (**)**)

Step 2 changes your input to this:

```
if ( a == 100 )
```

And after step 4 it looks like this:

```
if (( a == 100 ))
```

**Edit**: Shortcut by @voger

Steps 3 and 4 can be combined into the quicker <kbd>ysa))</kbd>.

Comment: That's a pretty cool plugin! Do you find yourself using it a lot during development?

Comment: I would add to the answer that there is no need for visual select. Put the cursor inside the parenthesis and do ysa)) and you have the same result.

Comment: @Rafael: Yes, it's probably in the top 5 of most crucial dev plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution for situations (easier to read) where you have to perform the change not only in some lines but in dozens of them where the manual action becomes boring.

Using a macro:

```
let @a="f[r(f]r)"

f[ ................ jump to the [
r( ................ replace with (
f] ................ jump to ]
r) ................ replace with )
```

Jump to the line where the change is needed and type @a

Using a global command:

```
:g/if \[/normal f[r(f]r)
:g/if \[/normal @a
```

Basically we are using the same commands both in the macro and in the global command. 
notice that the seccond global uses the 'a' macro defined above.